# CSS Menu - Submenu on click (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I downloaded [this](http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/responsive-flat-menu) menu. Seems to work good. But when you shrink the page the menu appears only when you click the button. Same for the subitems. But those subitems extends only when you click the "+" and not the "Products". I want to make it extend with **both** li (Products) and + symbol.

[Image of shrank menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Smlow.png)

The problem is in the .js file but I can't make it work.

```js
    (function($) {

  $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {
      
      var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({
        title: "Menu",
        format: "dropdown",
        sticky: false
      }, options);

      return this.each(function() {
        cssmenu.prepend('<div id="menu-button">' + settings.title + '</div>');
        $(this).find("#menu-button").on('click', function(){
          $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
          var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
          if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) { 
            mainmenu.hide().removeClass('open');
          }
          else {
            mainmenu.show().addClass('open');
            if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
              mainmenu.find('ul').show();
            }
          }
        });

        cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');

        multiTg = function() {
          cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
          cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
            if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
              $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
            }
            else {
              $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
            }
          });
        };

        if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
        else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');

        if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');

        resizeFix = function() {
          if ($( window ).width() > 768) {
            cssmenu.find('ul').show();
          }

          if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
            cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
          }
        };
        resizeFix();
        return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);

      });
  };
})(jQuery);

(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#cssmenu").menumaker({
   title: "Menu",
   format: "multitoggle"
});

});
})(jQuery);
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  background: #333333;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 17px;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 23px;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
  height: 35px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.15);
  padding: 11px 15px;
  width: 170px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.last-item > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  right: auto;
  left: 11px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  right: auto;
  left: 14px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 17px;
  height: 0;
}
@media all and (max-width: 768px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #cssmenu {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li,
  #cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
    height: auto;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li {
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 25px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 35px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    color: #dddddd;
    background: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,
  #cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
  #cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button {
    display: block;
    padding: 17px;
    color: #dddddd;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 17px;
    display: block;
    height: 4px;
    width: 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid #dddddd;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 17px;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
    top: 23px;
    border: 0;
    height: 2px;
    width: 15px;
    background: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button.menu-opened:before {
    top: 23px;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 15px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
    height: 46px;
    width: 46px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened {
    background: #262626;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button {
    height: 34px;
    width: 34px;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 19px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
    background: #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:after {
    top: 15px;
    right: 13px;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
    background: #ffffff;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 19px;
    right: 22px;
    display: block;
    width: 2px;
    height: 8px;
    background: #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:before {
    top: 12px;
    right: 16px;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang=''>
<head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
   <title>CSS MenuMaker</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
   <li class='active'><a href='#'>Products</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
               <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
               <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
<html>
```

**I would also like those sub-items centered.**

PS: My menu will have only one sublevel. EG: **Products > Product 1**.

Comment: That is most likely because on mobile devices(small screens) do not recognize the hover functionality. They will do the hover functionality when the user taps on the screen. There is an ontouchstart method, but it's basically the same as above.
For the centering of the item, we need to see the source code.

Comment: The "problem" is on both mobile devices and desktop. The source code is in the link.

Comment: What could be possibly so hard to apply `text-align:center` to the correct selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the sub-menu items of individual products in the HTML since there will only be 1 sub-level.

Relevant JS:

```
multiTg = function () {
  cssmenu.find(".has-sub")
    .prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>')
    .on("click", function () {
      submenuButton = $(this).find("span:first");
      submenuButton.toggleClass('submenu-opened');
      if (submenuButton.siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
        submenuButton.siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
      } else {
        submenuButton.siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
      }
   });

  /*
  cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
    if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
      $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
    } else {
      $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
    }
  });
  */
};
```

To center the submenu items

```
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > ul > li > a {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```js
    (function($) {

  $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {
      
      var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({
        title: "Menu",
        format: "dropdown",
        sticky: false
      }, options);

      return this.each(function() {
        cssmenu.prepend('<div id="menu-button">' + settings.title + '</div>');
        $(this).find("#menu-button").on('click', function(){
          $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
          var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
          if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) { 
            mainmenu.hide().removeClass('open');
          }
          else {
            mainmenu.show().addClass('open');
            if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
              mainmenu.find('ul').show();
            }
          }
        });

        cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');

        multiTg = function() {
          cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>')
              .on("click", function () {
                var submenuButton = $(this).find("span:first");
                submenuButton.toggleClass('submenu-opened');
                if (submenuButton.siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
                    submenuButton.siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
                } else {
                    submenuButton.siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
                };
              });

          /*
          cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
            if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
              $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
            }
            else {
              $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
            }
          });
          */
        };

        if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
        else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');

        if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');

        resizeFix = function() {
          if ($( window ).width() > 768) {
            cssmenu.find('ul').show();
          }

          if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
            cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
          }
        };
        resizeFix();
        return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);

      });
  };
})(jQuery);

(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#cssmenu").menumaker({
   title: "Menu",
   format: "multitoggle"
});

});
})(jQuery);
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  background: #333333;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 17px;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 23px;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > ul > li > a {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
  height: 35px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.15);
  padding: 11px 15px;
  width: 170px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.last-item > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  right: auto;
  left: 11px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  right: auto;
  left: 14px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 17px;
  height: 0;
}
@media all and (max-width: 768px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #cssmenu {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li,
  #cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
    height: auto;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li {
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 25px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 35px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    color: #dddddd;
    background: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,
  #cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
  #cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button {
    display: block;
    padding: 17px;
    color: #dddddd;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 17px;
    display: block;
    height: 4px;
    width: 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid #dddddd;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 17px;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
    top: 23px;
    border: 0;
    height: 2px;
    width: 15px;
    background: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button.menu-opened:before {
    top: 23px;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 15px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
    height: 46px;
    width: 46px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened {
    background: #262626;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button {
    height: 34px;
    width: 34px;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 19px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
    background: #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:after {
    top: 15px;
    right: 13px;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
    background: #ffffff;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 19px;
    right: 22px;
    display: block;
    width: 2px;
    height: 8px;
    background: #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:before {
    top: 12px;
    right: 16px;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang=''>
<head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
   <title>CSS MenuMaker</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
   <li class='active'><a href='#'>Products</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
         </li>
         <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Works but when I press the Product one it collapses. But it's not a real deal since anyway the page will refresh or change. But would be nice to be fixed. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This works with both `li` **(Product)** and `+` symbol and the sub-level menu.

Add this function call:

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

Here is the complete JavaScript code to make it work:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {
        var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({
            title: "Menu",
            format: "dropdown",
            sticky: false
        }, options);

        return this.each(function() {
            cssmenu.prepend('<div id="menu-button">' + settings.title + '</div>');

            $(this).find("#menu-button").on('click', function() {
                $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
                var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
                if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) {      
                    mainmenu.slideToggle().removeClass('open');
                }
                else {
                    mainmenu.show().addClass('open');
                    if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
                        mainmenu.find('ul').show();
                    }
                }
            });

            cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');

            multiTg = function() {
                cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>')
                .on("click", function (e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    var submenuButton = $(this).find("span:first");
                    submenuButton.toggleClass('submenu-opened');
                    if (submenuButton.siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
                        submenuButton.siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
                    } else {
                        submenuButton.siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
                    };
                });
            };

            if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
            else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');
            if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');

            resizeFix = function() {
                if ($( window ).width() > 768) {
                    cssmenu.find('ul').show();
                }
                if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
                    cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
                }
            };

            resizeFix();
            return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);
        });
    };  
})(jQuery);

(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
           title: "Sufi",
           format: "multitoggle"
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```